# How to hide some options or action in custom list item context Menu

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, custom-list

Hi I created a custom list and created some new item forms and these are displaying in more options when i select list item here how i disable other new item form that not in use.
also the Advanced option to allitems view.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using SharePoint Designer to create these custom forms?

If yes, you can hide the forms via the following actions:

1. Open site in SharePoint Designer
2. From left navigation choose Lists and Libraries
3. Open the list in question
4. Now from right pane - Look under "Custom Actions"
5. Select the action to delete
6. Use Ribbon "Delete" button OR press Delete key
   [image]

Comment: Hi thanks for reply i can able to remove new item that i dont want but also how can i remove advanced option ?

Comment: You can find the id of the elements that you want to hide, then use CSS code to hide the elements. a reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/228659/hide-sharepoint-suite-and-ribbon-bar.html